# Permutohedron Edge-Graph

Tags: abstract-algebra, polytopes, cayley-graphs

I am learning about Permutohedron's and I am having trouble determining how vertices are connected by edges. Wikipedia tells us that the edge-graph of a permutohedron is the Cayley graph of adjacent transpositions. There are two pictures on Wikipedia. The first one shows vertex $1423$ connected to vertex $1324.$ By analyzing the rest of the picture, I believe the vertices are connected if the number $1$ is swapped with number $2$, number $2$ is swapped with number $3$, or number $3$ is swapped with number $4$. (Also, the colouring of the first image on wikipedia is incorrect.)

[image]

However, there is another picture on wikipedia that shows vertex $1423$ connected to $1243.$ This could not be connected because number $2$ is swapped with number $4$ because $2$ and $4$ are not adjacent. However, upon further analysis it seems as though the vertices are connected if position $1$ is swapped with position $2,$ position $2$ with position $3,$ or position $3$ with position $4$.

Which picture, if any, is correct? What is the correct way to connect vertices of a permutohedron?

[image]

Comment: I suspect both are correct. They look different because they are using different conventions for representing the permutations attached to the vertices. (I've no time to figure out the details.) The coloring in the first image respects the zonoid structure; that in the second does not.

Comment: One is the "left permutohedron" (where two vertices are connected if the corresponding permutations are related by a swap of entries $i$ and $i+1$, which are not necessarily in adjacent positions), and the other is the "right permutohedron" (where two vertices are connected if the corresponding permutations are related by a swap of two entries in consecutive positions, nevermind what the values of these entries are). These permutohedra are isomorphic, since replacing each permutation by inverse takes one to the other.